# Certain parts of my CSS do not work

Tags: html, css

HTML CODE

```
<head>
    <title>Purdy designs</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>


<body>
<header class="navbar-inverse" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
          <nav>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    </div>
    </header>       





    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">

            <h1>
            Affordable website design packages from as low as &pound;199
            </h1>

            <p>
            Welcome to Purdy Website Design, If you need an affordable website to help you stand out from the crowd, you've come to the right place.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="offer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                 <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/242x200/f3f3f3/2d2d2d.png" alt="...">
                      <div class="caption">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Thumbnail 1</h3>
                        <p class="text-center">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row-fluid">
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/242x200/f3f3f3/2d2d2d.png" alt="...">
                      <div class="caption">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Thumbnail 2</h3>
                        <p class="text-center">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class="row-fluid">
                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/242x200/f3f3f3/2d2d2d.png" alt="...">
                      <div class="caption">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Thumbnail 3</h3>
                        <p class="text-center">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>





-----CSS------

.nav a {
color: #5a5a5a;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 14px 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;

}

.nav li {
display: inline; 
}

 .offer { 
   background-color: #f7f7f7;
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding: 4px;


  }

  .body {

   }

  .thumbnail h3 {
   font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: bold;  
   }

   .thumbnail{
   width: 250px;
   height: 400px;
     overflow: auto;
     }
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9vJh9Ny.png]

Here are my thumbnails, only certain parts of my CSS work. for instance -

```
.thumbnail{
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;

}
```

all parts of this code work, but when in other areas such as this -

```
.thumbnail h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
```

bold and 18px work, but the font does not change. It is also the same with other parts such as this -

```
.offer { 
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
```

some parts do not work. does anyone know why ?

CODEOPEN link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEzdGg

Comment: Firebug or another browser inspector would help you immensely.

Comment: paste your css into the w3 css validator and check for errors http://www.css-validator.org/

Comment: do you have the font installed ? is there inline styles overiding stylesheet styles ? have you done a reset ?

Comment: also use your browser tools to see if your css is being overridden by a more specific selector

Answer (score 3):

You're not loading a font-family called Shift. You need to load the font using @font-face, as well as reference it in your css.

Here's some guidance on how to load a font using @font-face:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

The .offer css is working just fine, but you declare a padding on all four sides *after* you declare 0 padding-top, so you still get a padding on top. Better rewrite that to:

```
.offer {
    padding: 0 4px 4px; // Padding every side except top.
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEzdGg here it is on code open, ill put it in the thread too.

Comment: @RobPurdy If my answer has resolved your issue please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.